# Change division background in FOR loop for a particular value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code,

```
<style type="text/css">
    .sample 
    {
        background:yellow;
        width:50%;
        border:1px solid #000;
        padding:5px;
        margin:2px;
        color:#fff;
        margin: 5px auto 0;
    }
</style>
<?php 
    for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++)
    {
        if($i == "2") { ?>
            <style type="text/css">
                .sample 
                {
                    background:red;
                    width:50%;
                    border:1px solid #000;
                    padding:5px;
                    margin:2px;
                    color:#fff;
                    margin: 5px auto 0;
                }
            </style>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="sample">
            <?php echo $i; ?> Sample Testing
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

In the above for loop i have to change the division `( sample )` background color to red , when the increment value`($i) is "2"`.

**NOTE:**

1. Without change the class name for the division.
2. JQuery is recommended for this.
3. Dont use inline styles.

Actually i have implemented one Jquery calender in one of projects. In that calender, users can book their slots (days). So i need to show that booked slots (days) in some different color. But we cant able to edit that default class name in Jquery.  So this the sample code, i generated related to that.

Please help me on this, If any useful answer will be really appreciate..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php to give inline style for a specific conditon like yours or you can toggle between different classes

*1) Using php*

```
<?php 
    for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++)
    {
        ?>
        <div class="sample" <?php if($i == 2){ echo "style='background:red;'"}?>>
            <?php echo $i; ?> Sample Testing
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Since you are so adamant about using jquery, you can try this way too

*2) Using jquery*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("div.sample:nth-child(2)").css('background', 'red');

});
```

Check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hkZKb/1/)

Comment: Please see my question. i want the output without change any classname or adding inline styles.

Comment: There is no mention of not adding inline styles. Why would you not want to do this? Please describe your situation in more detail as you apparently have unusual circumstances.

Comment: @ Wes C --> We cant add styles for that class.. because of in original case that class name was dynamically created by using jquery.. So this was the catch here.

Comment: @Sibu --> i ll appreciate your answer. but this doesn't use for my situation.

Comment: @hmb check my updated answer..will this help you??

Comment: @Sibu --> I saw the demo.. Could you please update your answer according with output code...

Comment: @hmb its already there !!!

Comment: @Sibu --> Thanks for your support.. I ll accept.. Question is worth or not...?